# Value not being recorded by .val()

Tags: jquery

I have the following date selection code in my project.
    
        
        Custom range report

```
        <div class="input-daterange input-group" id="class_date_range">
            <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control" id="report_date_start" name="report_date_start" />
            <span class="input-group-addon">to</span>
            <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control" id="report_date_end" name="report_date_end" />
        </div>

    </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

I am picking up the date using below code,

```
  $( ".centre-selection" ).each(function() {
        //$( this ).attr( 'href', '?module=<?=$_REQUEST['module']?>&Subject='+ $( this ).attr('data-subject')+ '&Centre_Selected_ID='+ $( this ).attr('data-centre')+ '&Class_Selected_Year='+ $( this ).attr('data-year')+ '&Class_Selected_All='+ $( this ).attr('data-all-centre')+ '&StartDate='+ $( this ).attr('report_date_start')+ '&EndDate='+ $( this ).attr('data-attendance-check-end'));
        $( this ).attr( 'href', '?module=<?=urlencode($_REQUEST['module']);?>
        &Subject='+ $('.subject-selected').val()+ 
        '&Centre_Selected_ID='+ encodeURIComponent($( this ).attr('data-centre')) + 
        '&Class_Selected_Year='+ encodeURIComponent($( this ).attr('data-year')) + 
        '&Class_Selected_All='+ encodeURIComponent($( this ).attr('data-all-centre')) +
        '&StartDate='+$('#report_date_start').val()+
        '&EndDate='+ $('#report_date_end').val());
      } );
```

Start date and end date values are not being picked up. I tried to print these values in an alert box and it prints it but for some reason it does not pick up the values in the above code.

Below it the url that gets generated when I click on the link:

```
http://localhost/school/admin/?module=module_progress_report&Subject=2&Centre_Selected_ID=20&Class_Selected_Year=year10&Class_Selected_All=undefined&StartDate=&EndDate=
```

Comment: what happens if you remove everything except the `.val()` call..

Comment: Where is `.subject-selected` in your html?

Comment: @CliffBurton:I did not place that code since there is no issue inside it.

Comment: without a self-contained example, no one else is going to be able to reproduce your problem...

Comment: @thebjorn: The date picker stops working in that case.

Comment: sure, but does the `.val()` pick up anything?  (also, do you need the php code in there for the problem to exist -- if yes, please add the php tag, if no, please remove it)

Comment: As the code is presented in the question, it is invalid: a quoted string cannot span multiple lines like you have it.  The line break before `&Subject='` is not allowed.

Comment: @thebjorn: Its strange that the program stops working when I change `<?` to `<?php`

Comment: Don't change `<?=`: it is fine.

Comment: works for me... https://jsfiddle.net/umnm6a3x/6/

Comment: Please don't link to images of text when you can (and should) put that text in your question.  Can you modify my jsfiddle so it demonstrates your problem?

Comment: @FahadUddin sorry, I misunderstood your request... Are you sure that your IDs `#report_date_start` and `#report_date_end` are unique in your entire markup?

Comment: @FahadUddin just a tip: to access data-prepended attributes in jQuery you can use `data("my-attribute")` instead of `attr("data-my-attribute")` reference: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/

Answer (score -1):

try with this;

```
$('#report_date_start').text()
```